# How to transfer a file to the server using sftp?

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

I'm new to PHP. I have the below details of my server. Now I need to upload (or move) a `.sql` file to the server from localhost application using SFTP. I've tried many and ended up with failures.

- Hostname
- Port Number
- Username
- Password
- Location

Please anyone give me a simple example to connect SFTP connection to my server to upload a file.

Comment: http://php.net/ssh2_sftp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to transmit a file and don't care about using `scp` or `sftp`, then I would encourage you to use `scp`. Here comes a basic example ([taken from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php)):

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('www.example.com', 22);
if($connection === FALSE) {
    die('Failed to connect');
}

$state = ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
if($state === FALSE) {
    die('Failed to authenticate');
}

$state = ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
if($state === FALSE) {
    die('Failed to transfer the file');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. how to catch the error?

Comment: You can only have a look at the return value. Check my update